# Langchain Retriever Agent Function Not Passing “ChatMessageHistory” When Called in Console - Python

Tags: langchain, py-langchain, pinecone

I am facing an issue with a Python function that I have created to handle some chat functionality with the GPT-3.5 Turbo model. The function is part of a bigger project that aims to use Pinecone to search and retrieve similar documents.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
def pineconeGPT(system, user, questions, answers, instruction, metadata={}):
    llm = ChatOpenAI(model='gpt-3.5-turbo-16k', temperature=0, openai_api_key="key")
    embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key="key", model="text-embedding-ada-002")
    pinecone.init(api_key='key', environment='region')
    index = Pinecone.from_existing_index('index_name', embeddings)
    history = ChatMessageHistory()
    if len(questions) > 0:
        for i in range(len(questions)):
            history.add_ai_message(questions[i])
            history.add_user_message(answers[i])
            
    retriever = index.as_retriever(search_type="similarity", search_kwargs={'filter': metadata})
    
    pineconeIndex = create_retriever_tool(
        retriever,
        "search_pinecone",
        "Searches and returns documents regarding the similarity."
    )
    
    tools = [pineconeIndex]
    
    system_message = SystemMessage(content=(system))
    prompt = OpenAIFunctionsAgent.create_prompt(system_message=system_message)
    
    agent = OpenAIFunctionsAgent(llm=llm, tools=tools, prompt=prompt)
    
    agent_executor = AgentExecutor(
        agent=agent,
        tools=tools,
        memory=ConversationBufferMemory(chat_memory=history),
        verbose=True,
        return_intermediate_steps=False,
        return_only_outputs=False
    )
    
    result = agent_executor({"input": instruction})
```

The history is included in the result but for example:

If the question is: What is your name?
Answer: My name is Bob

And the instruction says "what is my name"
ChatGPT response is saying I have not provided name.

This suggest that ChatGPT has not being passed the history by the agent.

I would appreciate any insights on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Anyone who had the same issue I way to fix it. 

    prompt = OpenAIFunctionsAgent.create_prompt(
        system_message=system_message,
        extra_prompt_messages = history.messages
    )
    
    I added extra_prompt_messages to pass history messages as a argument.